# Using split function to split the string but not getting desired result

Tags: java, split

want to split the string

```
    String vv = "class="fcg">1.6M";
    String[] breakvv = vv.split(">");
    String breakvv0 = parts[0]; 
    String breakvv1 = parts[1]; 
    System.out.println(breakvv0);
    System.out.println(breakvv1);
```

Output which i am getting is breakvv0 = an and breakvv1 = class="fcg">1.6M

Comment: Please fix your code so it compiles. We need a [mcve].

Comment: yes i have done that... will appreciate if you can help in getting the desirable result

Comment: No, you haven't.

Comment: String vv = "class=\"fcg\">1.6M"; does it sound better

Comment: Splitting that doesn't produce your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String vv = "class=\"fcg\">1.6M";
    String[] breakvv = vv.split(">");
    String breakvv0 = breakvv[0]; 
    String breakvv1 = breakvv[1]; 
    System.out.println(breakvv0);
    System.out.println(breakvv1);
```

Comment: not working getting output breakvv0 = an and breakvv1 = class="fcg">1.6M

Comment: kindly check the answer properly, expecially the part String breakvv0 = breakvv[0];  String breakvv1 = breakvv[1];

Comment: No problem , take care from next time, kindly close the question by accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String vv = "class=\"fcg\">1.6M";
        String[] breakvv = vv.split(">");
        String breakvv0 = breakvv[0]; 
        String breakvv1 = breakvv[1]; 
        System.out.println(breakvv0);
        System.out.println(breakvv1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: not working getting output breakvv0 = an and breakvv1 = class="fcg">1.6M

Comment: You were doing wrong String breakvv0 = parts[0]; 
    String breakvv1 = parts[1]; you should see my answer it is working fine